# Left join with a predicate on the inner table in the ON clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query like this:

Query 1)

```
select A.col1, B.col2
from A 
left join B on A.id= B.id and B.col3 = 'Hello';
```

I want to rewrite it to use a temp table for performance issue (I need the result the be exactly the same):

Query 2.1 and 2.2

```
Select B.id, B.col2 
into #temp
from B 
where B.col3 ='Hello';

select A.col1, t.col2
from A 
left join #temp AS t on A.id= t.id;
```

But my result is not the same (the temp table version has some `null`s in `B.col2` where the first version does not have).

Comment: Could you have some data samples and your result expects?

Comment: I couldn't see anything wrong so i created two tables and tried your two code samples - they give the same result - see [db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=36a93ebc1fa0963e7e5e16f1d422d0fb). What circumstances/data are you having issues with?

Comment: @seanb: Thanks (I have updated the question a bit). I don't understand...

Comment: I'm sorry, i still cannot see the issue. This is obviously a transposing of another query into an example one. Please check that's done correctly, or post original queries and tables.

Comment: @seanb. I will write if I find the problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @seanb: The problem was from something else I had overseem, so yes the two queries are the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for me, both queries have the same result

[image]

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: Thanks, yes the two versions are the same. I had overseen something else.. PS I think the norm here is to post the code and not the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

in your first query, you have LEFT join, this means all the rows from table A. Try inner join instead.

Comment: I want to rewrite the first query using a temp table. I don't want the result to change. I did not write the original query

Comment: it gave you only null or there are some errors? and what is the meaning of different nulls? if it gives you null but in your original query did not then may by the id you are looking for is not in the temp table or if there is any other error please describe it

Comment: check your tables like select * from #tem and select * from A and select * from B is there any data available or no